# captureing URL from packet header

Tags: c#, .net, pcap, packet-sniffers

I want to capture streaming video

so I saw URL Getter software and it is good because it gave me the streaming link.

then I tried to make one my self so I used PCAP.net library on vb.net 2010

finally I got the link on that code >>

```
If packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim text = Encoding.Default.GetString(packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload.ToMemoryStream().ToArray())
                Dim match = Regex.Match(text.ToLower(), "(?<=[get|post])\s(?<Path>/.*?)[\?\s].*?http/1\.1.*?host:\s(?<Host>[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline)

                    MyStr = match.Groups("Host").Value & match.Groups("Path").Value


            End If
```

but it doesn't work because I realize that URL Getter get the link with the parameters ..

so My software get the link like this >> http://www.example.com/stream 
but URL Getter get it like this >> http://www.example.com/stream?ID=0001

so how can I get the link with the paramters ????

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about something easily searcheable on the internet and shows no attempts at solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should only read the first line of the request and parse that
2. You can use the `Uri` class to get just some part of the URI.

However, do note that the query string is a part of the request. You probably don't want to throw it away.

Comment: excuse me how can I read the first line of the request ?? sorry   could you give me an example ??

Comment: You can use the `StreamReader` class, or even just find `0D0A` (CRLF) in the byte stream first and only decode the data up to that point. HTTP requests can be very large :)

Comment: Do you have another solution ?? or good example do that in vb.net or C# ??

Comment: Oh, you want the query string. Well, you have to fix your RegEx, then, because it's ignoring that :) Why not instead just parse the line manually? Read the HTTP method, and the rest is the URI. It really is quite simple :)

Comment: thank you for the help
t works by replace the regex by 

    "(?<=[get|post])\s(?<Path>/.*)\shttp/1\.1.*?host:\s(?<Host>[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]*)"